# Is storage capacity a relevant aspect for hardware compatibility?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, compatibility

I'm planning on buying an internal M.2 2280 SSD card for my computer (Acer Swift SF113-31) and I'm thinking about buying a WD Blue 3D NAND. I've learned from multiple comments on oficial forums that this card is compatible, but also that the computer is also unable to support a SSD with more than 256 Gb. Now, **is that even possible?** I have not been able to find an official answer from Acer.

Is it possible that a modern computer supports a SSD card of 256Gb, but it cannot support another card using identical technology and from the same manufacturer, but with higher capacity? Not even that much more: I'd like to buy a 512Gb card.

My biggest concern is I don't want to, due to ignorance, either spend my money on a card smaller than another compatible one that I would prefer, or buy a bigger one that is unusable.

I come to stackexchange because it's the community I trust the most. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will be easier for people to respond if they know the context for the claim of a 256 GB maximum.  Can you add a link or two to where you saw that?

Comment: As you can see from these threads in Acer's Community forums, information is contradictory: 

[Thread 1](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/551701/swift-1-sf113-31-p5ck-upgrade-to-ssd-m-2-500gb)
[Thread 2](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/546338/swift-1-not-detecting-m-2-120gb-hp-s700-ssd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system can take drives.larger then 250gigs. The crucial website specifically certifies even 1tb drives for it - https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/acer-swift-3#SSDFilters

The issues on the forum - and indeed it seems to be only 1 preson making a questionable claim - could theoretically relate to a hardware whitelist in the BIOS - although this is unlikely, and it appears that if it were, newer BIOS's remove the limit or extend compatibility.

From a general POV inless the vendor.is locking down compatible software in BIOS, amy ssd up to 2tb shluld easily be supported. On older devices - probably way older then your laptop and M2 drives - there may be some cimpatibility issues with drives over 2tb due to disk geometry. This is not the issue here.

Comment: (Not that there are very many ssds that have a capacity greater than 2 TB on the market).  There isn’t anything in the M.2 standard that would specifically allow for a 256 GB to be allowed but make a 512 GB incompatible.  This is the complete opposite situation of SATA controllers a few years ago where older controllers might have a capacity limit.  *I am describing about SATA controllers made when 4 TB was the largest drive.*. Engineers sometimes make stupid design restrictions early in a standards life cycle.  M.2 being based off SATA and PCIe didn’t have that problem.